# How can I make certain rows/cells read-only with the JVX Framework?

Tags: jvx

I have a table with several records and now I want to make individual entries that have a certain value set in a column read-only, or exclusively this one cell of the record. Is there a way to do this with the JVX framework?

I have checked the documentations, but there is not the right one for my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with an [readonly checker](https://www.sibvisions.com/files/jvx/current/api/javax/rad/model/event/IReadOnlyChecker.html). Just set the readonly checker on a databook and implement your rules.

If this doesn't work because some technologies don't support this feature, it's also possible to use afterRowSelected and afterColumnSelected events to dis-/enable the whole table.

Disabling single cells is not nice for users because it means that direct table editing is enabled... just sayin.